# PHP Doctrine: generation problem?

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm generating models from my Mysql db. It generates a foreign key collection properly, but not the other way around... **Is this supposed to be 'by-design', or am i doing something wrong?**

**pseudo code alert**

```
User:
  UserId pk
  LocationId fk     //User location

Location
  LocationId pk
  UserId fk         //Location owner
```

Generated code:

```
class User() {
    hasMany('Location') //for locations owned by the user

    //BUT NOT THIS ONE:
    //hasOne('Location_1') //for current location of user
}

class Location() {
    hasMany('User') //for users which are on that location

    //AND NOT THIS ONE
    //hasOne('User_1') //for location owner
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an association table. Your pseudo code is misleading – in *many to many* relationship, no foreign keys are used in User or Location classes, but in association class.

See [PDF manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/pdfs/manual-1-2-pl.pdf) page 76.

Comment: No, the code is right. This doesn't need an association class, it needs a one-to-many relationship TWO times.

Comment: User->locationid is updated whenever the location of a user changes. When a Location is inserted, a User is assigned as it's owner.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Just a guess, but maybe you should explicitly define _owningSide_? http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models#relationships

Comment: I'm really missing something somewhere. Please correct me but: let's say there is one foreign key relation where User.LocationId links to Location.Id. This means Doctrine will generate Location->hasMany('User'). But doesn't this imply there should be a User->hasOne('Location') generated also?

Comment: I wouldn't count on that, since the manual says: _"Generating from existing databases is only meant to be a convenience for getting started. After you generate from the database you will have to tweak it and clean things up as needed."_ http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/introduction-to-models#generating-models

Comment: Ah ok, no problem, but I can just enter the hasOne for the other table and everything should be fine then? :)

Comment: Yes, you can (should) fine-tune your automatically generated classes to fit your needs.